# С typecasting in conditions

Tags: c, if-statement, implicit-conversion, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

There is a simple example:

```
unsigned a = -5;
int b = 5;
if (a + b <= -1){
...
}
```

To which type will cast `a+b`? To signed or unsigned? And is it noted in C-standard or compiler will decide what to do?

Comment: Duplicate: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). I'll refrain from dupe-voting since I'm partial (the post author).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the usual arithmetic conversions if two objects have the same rank then an object of signed integer type is converted to the unsigned integer type.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.

and (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed.

So in this condition

```
if (a + b <= -1){
```

the both operands `a + b` and `-1` are converted to the type `unsigned int`.

That is as `a` has the type `unsigned int` then and the expression `a + b` also has the type `unsigned int`. As the expression `a + b` has the type `unsigned int` then and the expression `-1` will also have the type unsigned int (`-1` will be converted to the maximum value of the type `unsigned int`).

Thus the condition of the if statement will evaluate to the logical `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, be careful of your terminology:

> To which type will cast a+b?

A cast is an *explicit* conversion (eg `(int)(a)`)... this is an *implicit* conversion!

But isn't C a great language...

Consider:

```
unsigned a = -5;
```

Any sensibly defined language would throw an error, when assigning a negative number to an unsigned variable...

Consider, further `( unsigned int + signed int )`: the OP is not the first, nor will be the last, to get confused by the implicit type promotions in the C language - some of which are even less obvious than this...  the answer is that this will result in an `unsigned int` (unsigned + signed = unsigned).

Then the potential Heisenbug (and/or maybe a Schrodinger's Bug):

```
if ( unsigned int <= -1 )
```

By definition, an unsigned integer cannot be less than zero, so the resultant  `IF` clause is unreachable, and may well be optimised away.  However, the `-1` will be actually be promoted to an `unsigned integer` as *UINT_MAX* and therefore this becomes `if ( unsigned int <= UINT_MAX )`, which of course is always `true`, and you have an unconditional conditional.

Of course, you might not really care whether this is unconditionally true, unconditionally false, or the wrong answer...

But most of the time, this matters... So, how do you protect yourself?

MISRA C introduces the concept of the *Essential Type Model*, which has guidelines to protect you from unexpected type conversions - Section 8.10 of the book (including a number of Rules) plus two appendices.

**Edit:** `<=` not just `<` as per the OP ;-)

(see profile for affiliation)

Comment: `a + b <= -1` is not a Heisenbug nor a Schrödinger bug, and `unsigned int < UINT_MAX` is not always true.

Comment: No, but `unsigned int <= UINT_MAX` is ;-)

Comment: "this will result in an unsigned int (unsigned + signed = signed)" - I think you meant that to be "unsigned + signed = unsigned", otherwise the statement contradicts itself.

Comment: Doh! Yes, you are correct!

Comment: Appreciated the answer, and amused by your "unconditional conditional"! Would it be better "Unconditional condition"?

Comment: That one was deliberate... glad you liked it!